# Angular new project not working visual studio code intellisense

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-cli, intellisense

I have problem with new Angular project created via Angular CLI.

I create base angular project via

```
ng new test-project
```

then open this directory in vscode. And when i try to import ReactiveForms module inside main module import settings, vscode doesn't recognize this module, and has no intellisense at all.

Even inside component constructor, vscode doesn't helping.

But, when I download some example project from net, based on Angular 5.0, intellisense is there.

Thanks for help.

> Angular CLI: 1.7.4 Node: 9.10.1 npm: 5.8.0 OS: darwin x64 (macOS High
>   Sierra)

Comment: try updating your VSCode

Comment: version 1.22.1 (1.22.1)

Answer (score 1):

First, download angular extentions in vscode then do the proper imports.

1) In visual studio code, hit Cntrl+shift+X to open the extension search tab.
Then search and install the angular extensions if you don't have.
Specially, download the Angular language service & typescript ones.

2) Once you have those, then to use the the forms control have your app module look like this

```
import { NgModule }            from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }       from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';  // <-- #1 import module

import { AppComponent }        from './app.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule // <-- #2 add to @NgModule imports
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

// Good to have angular extensions for vscode
https://scotch.io/bar-talk/best-vs-code-extensions-for-angular-v2-development